# Wso2 Identity Server with mssql and ReadOnlyLDAP for OAuth

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, wso2-identity-server

We are trying to use wso2 5.1.0 Identity server for OAuth authentication.
We want to use mssql database in order to have multiple server node.

I configure readolyLDAP user store and created database in mssql. I did all necessary configuration as per given link

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Setting+up+Microsoft+SQL
https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Setting+up+the+Database

Every thing is works fine and server started successfully with out any error.
Then i setup service provider app for OAuth authentication.

All OAuth call working fines i.e

- https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token
- https://localhost:9443/oauth2/revoke
- https://localhost:9443/oauth2/userinfo?schema=openid

Except refresh token call
https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token

Its giving error as follow

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-05-29 18:12:47,350] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.AccessTokenIssuer} -  Error occurred while validating grant 
org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.IdentityOAuth2Exception: Error when validating a refresh token
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenMgtDAO.validateRefreshToken(TokenMgtDAO.java:733)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.RefreshGrantHandler.validateGrant(RefreshGrantHandler.java:66)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.AccessTokenIssuer.issue(AccessTokenIssuer.java:154)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service.issueAccessToken(OAuth2Service.java:196)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.token.OAuth2TokenEndpoint.getAccessToken(OAuth2TokenEndpoint.java:245)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.token.OAuth2TokenEndpoint.issueAccessToken(OAuth2TokenEndpoint.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:188)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:104)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:204)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:101)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:249)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:289)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:209)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:265)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CSRFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CSRFPreventionFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CRLFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CRLFPreventionFilter.java:59)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'TOKEN_SCOPE'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:404)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:285)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenMgtDAO.validateRefreshToken(TokenMgtDAO.java:689)
    ... 60 more
```

I explore error log and found that the problem is with sql query 
https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity/blob/master/components/oauth/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/oauth2/dao/TokenMgtDAO.java

code use different sql queries as per datatype

```
mySqlQuery = SQLQueries.RETRIEVE_ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDATION_DATA_MYSQL.replaceAll("\\$accessTokenStoreTable",
                    accessTokenStoreTable);
db2Query = SQLQueries.RETRIEVE_ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDATION_DATA_DB2SQL.replaceAll("\\$accessTokenStoreTable",
                    accessTokenStoreTable);
oracleQuery = SQLQueries.RETRIEVE_ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDATION_DATA_ORACLE.replaceAll("\\$accessTokenStoreTable",
                    accessTokenStoreTable);
msSqlQuery = SQLQueries.RETRIEVE_ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDATION_DATA_MSSQL.replaceAll("\\$accessTokenStoreTable",
                    accessTokenStoreTable);
informixQuery = SQLQueries.RETRIEVE_ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDATION_DATA_INFORMIX.replaceAll
                    ("\\$accessTokenStoreTable", accessTokenStoreTable);
postgreSqlQuery = SQLQueries.RETRIEVE_ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDATION_DATA_POSTGRESQL.replaceAll
                    ("\\$accessTokenStoreTable", accessTokenStoreTable);
```

http://mail.wso2.org/mailarchive/commits/2015-July/104690.html
table IDN_OAUTH2_SCOPE_ASSOCIATION is missing in database.

is there any way i can resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known issue in IS 5.1.0 according to [1]. Fix will be available in 5.2.0 release. You can find the fix from the pull request in the Jira ticket.

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-4532